# Replace LF Demilimted with other delimiter

Tags: sql

I have single varchar(2000) column, looks like,

```
12:10:08: Dialing12:10:08: Connecting12:10:08: ABC: abc:9433769781$100.88.77.0:878712:10:08: ABCD: 000012:10:09: Agent Initializing12:10:25: On Call12:10:25: Assigned to operator12:10:25: Waiting for Supervisor12:10:30: Waiting for Manager12:11:30: Call Ended12:11:30: Call Not connected..
```

This is actually delimited by LF.

Is there anyway we can put a delimiter in every interval. Such as

```
12:10:08: Dialing|12:10:08: Connecting|12:10:08: ABC: abc:9433769781$100.88.77.0:878712:10:08: ABCD: 0000|12:10:09: Agent Initializing|12:10:25: On Call|12:10:25: Assigned to operator|12:10:25: Waiting for Supervisor|12:10:30: Waiting for Manager|12:11:30: Call Ended|12:11:30: Call Not connected.
```

Comment: consider using replace functions. have it look at the ascii characters for LF and replace it with a |.  but are you sure it's LF and not CRLF?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. That's what source data designer said. :) ASCII character for LF is 10.Lets try

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx + http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx = win.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e02c/2/0

Example:

```
create table test(
  data varchar(2000))

insert into test (data) values ('This is a' + char(10)+'Test');

Select replace(data,char(10),'|') from test;
```

yields:

```
This is a|Test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression.  At least you can do that in DB2 with xQuery